# Stored functions postgresql returning table

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.1

A novice when it comes to stored procedures/functions. I have searched Google, Stackoverflow, and Youtube and are finding all sorts of examples that are convoluted, some not in English.

I'm trying to understand the basic syntax for a stored function to return a table in Postgresql. In MySql this is elementary but I can't seem to wrap my head around the syntax for Postgresql I have the SQL statement I need to return the rows I want (table), as seen below. I have tried the following code but it doesn't work. Help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Getcurrent()
RETURNS table AS $schedule$

$BODY$ BEGIN

SELECT *
FROM archived_table
WHERE table_id>=ALL(SELECT table_id FROM archived_table);

RETURN schedule;
END;$BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

********** Error **********

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 2: RETURNS table AS $schedule$
                      ^
```

This is the error message.

I have referenced the following link and have had no luck with this.https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html
Im using pgAdminIII, in the public schema, on my company's server.

The desired results is to have the table returned once the function is called.

Comment: `returns table` requires the columns list as shown in the manual link you posted.

Comment: Unrelated, but: if you intend to return the row with the highest `table_id` there are much more efficient ways of doing that in Postgres.

Comment: Also: "*In MySql this is elementary*" no it's not because you can't return a result set from a function there.

Answer (score 1):

`RETURNS TABLE` is not complete, hence the error message.

You can use the `RETURNS SETOF <table_name>` form, if you intend to return all columns of a table.

Otherwise, you'll need to mention every output column by name and type, with either [`RETURNS TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE):

```
RETURNS TABLE (
   col_alias_1 INT,
   col_alias_2 TEXT,
   col_alias_3 <some_other_type>,
   ...
)
```

Or with [`OUT` parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-OUTPUT-PARAMETERS) + `RETURNS SETOF RECORD` to indicate that you'll (possibly) return multiple rows at once.

Also, if your operation is as simple as a few SQL statements, use `LANGUAGE SQL` instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Getcurrent()
  RETURNS SETOF archived_table
  LANGUAGE SQL
AS $BODY$
  SELECT *
  FROM archived_table
  WHERE table_id>=ALL(SELECT table_id FROM archived_table);
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Pozs your second box worked like a charm, thanks.  I'm in the midst of learning more about stored procedures and I'm not really sure how to implement the "returns setof record"